# How can I set up "PrintTitleRows" in EPPlus?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, epplus, epplus-4

In Excel Interop, I can set up title rows to repeat on subsequent pages like so:

```
_xlSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = String.Format("${0}:${0}", COLUMN_HEADING_ROW);
```

How is it accomplished in EPPlus? I tried prodding Intellisense to giving me a clue by typing:

```
prodUsageWorksheet.PrinterSettings.
```

...but no "Print" (except "PrintArea") or "Title" offered itself to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to set the `RepeatRows`:

```
prodUsageWorksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = new ExcelAddress("$1:$1");
```